# create-react-app uploaded images are not fetched

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack, create-react-app

I have a problem with images in create react app i can not use "webpack import" way of including images because i am uploading them and then i want to show them.

my code of img is simple

```
<img src={file.path} alt={title}/>
```

which gets rendered as:

```
<img src="/public/cdn/files/offer_photo/a70318372a62066c492b4ebdd34491af8bd9bb15.jpg" alt="rez5d9e85_id20150826_036" class="MuiGridListTile-imgFullHeight-620">
```

as per [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) in development i should use `/public` folder to let webpack server to server it. But it seems it doesn't

- the file is in place
- i have tried to add `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` pre-fix to dynamically added img src ..did not helped.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is `file.path`? And do you have `homepage` set in `package.json` or use the `PUBLIC_URL` env var?

In your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53696665/1) it seems like you got a 200 when requesting the image. Is the image there, when you look at the response?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to assign the import of the image to a variable? example

```
const image = require ('path to image')
and then:
<img src={image} />
```

Comment: As i stated in question i can not require files due fact i am uploading them and then showing them (images)..so i dont have files beforehand